# Passing an IEnumerable model FROM Index View (which uses the lower level model class to a Details view (which uses a ViewModel class)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Looking for help in understanding how I can pass an id value from an INDEX view which is bound the base model PlacementOrganisation) to the DETAILS view in the same controller which instead references a viewmodel which (apologies if the language is incorrect) combines this object with a related Placement object.

The PlacementOrganisation class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Placementv2.Models
{
    public class PlacementOrganisation
    {
        public int PlacementOrganisationID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The "wrapper" PlacementOrganisationIndexData ViewModel class is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Placementv2.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Web;
using IdentitySample.Models;
using PagedList;
namespace Placementv2.ViewModels
{
    public class     PlacementOrganisationIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<PlacementOrganisation> PlacementOrganisations { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Placement> Placements { get; set; }


    }
}
```

My controller includes a number of controller actions including an Index view as follows which via debugging I've confirmed is correctly passing the id of the record to the details view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using IdentitySample.Models;
using Placementv2.Models;
using Placementv2.ViewModels;
using PagedList;

namespace Placementv2.Controllers
{
    // [RequireHttps] 

    [Authorize(Roles = "UserAdmin")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SysAdmin")]

    public class PlacementOrganisationsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: PlacementOrganisations
   public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, int page = 1)
    {
        var organisations = from s in db.PlacementOrganisations
                            select s;

        return View(organisations.ToPagedList(page, 10));

    }
```

The Index view of the PlacementOrganisations Controller is as follows:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Placementv2.Models.PlacementOrganisation>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PlacementOrganisations", FormMethod.Get))
{ <p> Find an Organisation : @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string) <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
      @Html.ActionLink("Clear Search", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
   </p> }


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>

                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PlacementOrganisationID }) |
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<br />
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }),
        PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
```

I have more or less parked the PlacementOrganisations Details view for now as I'm having such difficulty in binding the ViewModel to the incoming id from the Index view.

The reason I want to use a ViewModel here is to show the user information on both the PlacementOrganisation and also the Placements associated with this PlacementOrganisation in a single view.

My issue is that I cannot get at the ID property in the PlacementOrganisation object within the Viewmodel object to bind it to the id.

I've tried poking around extensively in Intellisense to find the properties I need but can't find it. I've also reviewed related questions previously asked on S/O but none of these seem to be exactly like this.

(Am not ashamed as a newb to concede this may be because I'm going about this the wrong way!)
Here's the closest I've got so far

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{

    var organisationModel = new PlacementOrganisationIndexData();


    organisationModel.PlacementOrganisations= db.PlacementOrganisations.Find(id);


    PopulateCountiesDropDownList(OrganisationModel.PlacementOrganisations.);
    PopulatePlacementTypesDropDownList(ViewBag.PlacementTypeID);
    return View(organisationModel);

    }
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this issue.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I have edited it back to the relevant pieces

Comment: Yes my problem is after I redirect from the Index view to the details I have instantiated an instance of the PlacementOrganisationIndexData object and am then I am really struggling to bind this specific object to the PlacementOrganisation in the database represented by the ID that was passed in to the Details Controller action

Comment: Hi it references the ViewModel as follows:                                        @model Placementv2.ViewModels.PlacementOrganisationIndexData
           
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Placement Organisation Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this- I don't fully understand the question, apologies! The project namespace is Placementv2 and I've placed the indexdata viewmodel class in a separate viewmodels folder instead of in the models folder as this is the approach taken in the tutorial examples on viewmodels I've learned from on the asp.net and Pluralsight examples. Sorry if that doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured it out. The code below returns an IndexData object which is in turn composed of two ienumerables which I can then use in my view

```
  public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            var viewModel = new PlacementOrganisationIndexData();
            viewModel.PlacementOrganisations = db.PlacementOrganisations.Where(p => p.PlacementOrganisationID == id.Value);
            viewModel.Placement= db.Placements.Where(c => c.PlacementOrganisationID == id.Value);

            return View(viewModel);

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Didn't mean to cause any offence just felt it would be more useful to have the correct answer to the question posed marked as the accepted answer. I very much appreciated your endeavours in trying to help but although well meant apart from changing to nullable int the rest of your comments just weren't relevant. I had initially thought your answer was on the right track but then realised that it wasn't afterwards and figured it out myself. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add a question mark in your parameters.

And change the first two lines of your method to the one line.

you also have an extraneous fullstop.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    var organisationModel= db.PlacementOrganisations.Find(id);
    // Remove fullstop from end of line below
    PopulateCountiesDropDownList(OrganisationModel.PlacementOrganisations.);
    PopulatePlacementTypesDropDownList(ViewBag.PlacementTypeID);
    return View(organisationModel);
}
```

I'm not sure why you have put this in the ViewModels namespace. I would have thought that the
Models namespace would be where it should go, as the controller is accessing data from this namespace.

```
namespace Placementv2.ViewModels
```

to

```
namespace Placementv2.Models
```

Also, within your application database context you may need to add these classes.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :  DbContext // Or what ever your database
                                               // context has
{

    public DbSet<PlacementOrganisation> PlacementOrganisations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Placement> Placements { get; set; }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, please let me know.

Comment: thank you for your help. the line var organisationModel= db.PlacementOrganisations.Find(id); was what I was missing